# Python osgeo/OGR not returning all features in PBF

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

I have a PBF file that is a limited export of the Nepal area. I'm trying to pull out all the adminstrative boundaries.

If I use `osmconvert` to turn my PBF file into a OSM file, sure enough I see the outer national boundary for Nepal in it:
  https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/184633#map=7/28.416/84.128

```
<relation id="184633" version="428" timestamp="2020-01-11T00:26:39Z" changeset="79439437" uid="4892967" user="XD346">
        <member type="way" ref="744544230" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="35550176" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="45325045" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="331271373" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="201928163" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="331310291" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="201928153" role="outer"/>
        <member type="way" ref="393979068" role="outer"/>
        ....
```

However if I build a simple Python script to echo out all the features from the same source PBF file, that relation is not present:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

datasource = ogr.Open("/Users/nicp/nyaruka/posm/nepal/admin_levels.pbf")

layerCount = datasource.GetLayerCount()

for i in range(layerCount):
    layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(i)
    print(f"{i}: {layer.GetName()}")

    feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
    while feat is not None:
        print(feat.GetField("osm_id"))
        feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
```

What's going on here? Is there something I'm missing?

PBF File: https://nyaruka.com/sitestatic/nepal.pbf

Pip Freeze:

```
GDAL==2.4.4
numpy==1.18.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
PyYAML==5.3
Rtree==0.9.4
Shapely==1.7.0
six==1.12.0
```

Comment: Impossible to say without being a GDAL developer. I made a test with ogrinfo and  also with nepal-latest.osm.pbf and that boundary relation is not found. Other relations of type "old_boundary" are found.

Comment: Thanks, well at least I'm not totally crazy / incompetent. Does seem some tools extract it ok but the OGR libraries don't. Ended up getting what I needed from https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/ in the end which addressed my immediate need.